# How to handle touch event when touching fingerprint sensor on Android?

Tags: android

I want an application that when I touch fingerprint sensor, it can do special things like back, home or touch screen. I do not need an authentication of any fingerprint, only respond touch event. Are there any callbacks to invoke, or I need root or Xposed?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: nothing, only read some developer documents about fingerprintmanager, but they.are helpless

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Accessibility Service (not as stable), or by using Xposed Framework.

This app on the play store does exactly this - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aecampos.android.fingerprintgestures

It also has an xposed version, that is more stable (source code's on github) - http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ztc1997.fingerprint2sleep